How does assembler allocate memory for machine code and know what address to jump to for an external function?
I have been studying the C compilation process but cannot find an answer to this question.
The source and object codes are produced before the linking process. A code like this will compile into a .s or .o file with no problem.
int add (int a, int,b);

int main(){
int tmp = add(1,2);
return 0;
}

At this stage, the compiler or the assembler does not know the length of the add function, but a memory section must be allocated as text for the add function. For example, in the assembly output, to execute the add function, there will be a jump instruction to the add function. How will the assembler know the address of the add function in this stage?
What does the assembler do in this step?
Does the assembler reserve some amount of memory for the possible add function?

Note, there is no assembler involved at all. Watch this : What Happens After The Compiler in C++ (How Linking Works) - Anders Schau Knatten - C++ on Sea 2023

I will be watching the video as soon as possible. And can you explain further how no assembler is involved at all

The C++ code is directly compiled to binary code (no assembler is involved).  Though you can inspect assembly code here if you'd like : https://godbolt.org/z/fe9cTr57d. And you will see a placeholder token :  add(int, int)@PLT that the linker later can resolve later.

I see. And about the object codes, when I objectdump a .o file, do the objdump reassemble the machine code to the assembly code?

No not really, it reads the "opcodes" and shows them as assembly instructions. None of the names of the original C/C++ code will show up. (Unless you have a smart tool, like a debugger, that can also read debug info files)

"How will the assembler know the address of the add function in this stage?" and "Does the assembler reserve some amount of memory for the possible add function?" are both answered by the link step, i.e. when a.o and b.o (containing add()) are combined into an executable program file, if you will.  Remember a.o is not executable, it is an incomplete fragment.

@PepijnKramer: Some C++ compilers go straight from their internal representation to machine code, no asm text ever exists.  But not all: GCC really does write a .s file (or pipe it) to an assembler which it invokes as a separate process.  You can ask clang to emit a .s that assembles to exactly the same .o it would have made directly.  (MSVC asm listings sometimes include extraneous stuff and can't necessarily be assembled to exactly the .obj it makes.)  Either way, the end result is machine code in the .text section of an object file which has symbols and other metadata.

@PeterCordes Thanks for that info, my mental model was that must current compilers internally builds up some "intermediate language" model internally, optimize that with heuristics and then convert that to machine code directly.

@PepijnKramer: Most major compilers do, GCC doesn't.  See Does a compiler always produce an assembly code? for some discussion of the reasons why, and why smaller more obscure compilers also often just go to asm (leaving object-file handling to a separate program, for different OSes on the same architecture.)

The object module contains information telling the linker what changes need to be made when the object module is linked with other object modules.
There are multiple object module formats, so the information in this answer is general and conceptual. Suppose there is a call instruction in the program. In the assembly language, it might look like call add. Say the machine language code for a call instruction is 0x73 followed the four-byte address of the routine to be called. Then, in the text section in the object module, the assembler would write five bytes: 0x73 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00. There is another part of the object module called a relocation table that lists places that need to be changed when the module is linked. These are often called “fixups.” In this table, the assembler will put information about this call instruction. An entry in this table will provide information about each change to be made, including:

Which program section is to be changed.
Where in the program section the change is (by bytes from its start).
What type of change it is.
The name of the symbol referred to.

So, for example the table entry for call add might indicate it is in the text section, 34 bytes from the start, that it is a whole replacement of the address, and the name of the symbol is add. When the linker decides where add will be located in the program, it writes that address into the text section, 34 bytes from the start.
That is a simplified example using an absolute address. It is more common these days that a relative address would be used. Instead of taking an absolute address, an instruction will calculate an address as an offset from the current program counter, which contains the address of the instruction the processor is executing or is about to execute. With relative addressing, the relocation entry says the type of change is relative instead of absolute. Then the linker, instead of writing the absolute address into the text section, will calculate the difference between the call destination and the address of the call instruction (or its following instruction) and write that difference into the text section.
Other codes for the type of change might indicate that a symbol value has to be added to the data already in the text section, instead of wholly replacing it, or that a value has to be fit into a bit-field in a particular type of instruction or encoded in a particular way. But the general idea is the same: The values in the text section contain initial information, and a relocation table indicates how to change the values when linking the program (possibly including linking that occurs when loading the program into memory).

great and through explanation, thank you! Can I objectdump my .o file to see the table you have mentioned?

@ErinçUtkuÖztürk Yes, according to the man page, objdump --syms dumps the symbol table.  objdump -drwC adds relocation entries as annotations to the disassmbly, so you can see where the placeholder call is going in a .o.  You can also use nm to see the symbol table.  readelf can show you lots of stuff about ELF object files and executables, including the symbol table.  readelf -a /bin/ls for example will show all the symbols it wants from shared libraries, plus lots more about its sections and segments.  Or use it on a .o that hasn't been linked.

The C compiler translates the source code into an assembly code (.s file). Since add is only declared but not defined, the compiler knows the signature (parameters and return type) but doesn't know the implementation. It treats add as an external symbol and assumes the definition will be provided later (likely in another object file or library).The assembler converts the assembly code into machine code, creating an object file (.o file).he assembler creates an entry for the add function in the symbol table as an undefined symbol.The assembler does not reserve memory for the add function. Instead, it simply records the fact that add is a function that will be resolved during the linking phase. During linking, the linker combines all object files and resolves the addresses for external symbols like add. If the linker cannot find a definition for add, it will throw an undefined reference error.
You could read more about it here : https://www.quora.com/What-happens-if-a-function-is-declared-but-not-defined-in-C
